# Which Parameter needs a Case in a switch to call a method of an object?

Tags: c#, object, parameters, switch-statement

i want to build a piggy Bank Application in C# with the class moneyBox. Now i have got some problems to call a Method for change the coin propertys in my object. I want to build the switch like an menu with case Deposit by call my method. The Case "Deposit Money" needs a parameter to call the method, but i don't know which parameter it needs. Maybe someone can help me.

```
class Program
{
    public static List<moneyBox> moneyBoxes = new List<moneyBox>();

    

    public static void AddmoneyBox()
    {
        moneyBox myMoneyBox = new moneyBox();
        Console.WriteLine("Nennen Sie den Namen Ihres neuen Sparschweins:");
        myMoneyBox.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        moneyBoxes.Add(myMoneyBox);
    }   

    

    static void DepositMoney(moneyBox myMoneyBox)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie an wie viele einzelne Cent und Euro Stücke sie einzahlen möchten:");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele ein Cent Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.OneCent += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele zwei Cent Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.TwoCent += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele fünf Cent Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.FiveCent += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele zehn Cent Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.TenCent += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele zwanzig Cent Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.TwentyCent += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele fünfzig Cent Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.FifftyCent += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele ein Euro Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.OneEuro += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Wie viele zwei Euro Münzen möchten Sie einzahlen?");
        myMoneyBox.TwoEuro += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
         
        
    }

    public static void PrintMoneyBoxes(moneyBox newMoneyBox)
    {
        newMoneyBox.SumEuro = newMoneyBox.OneEuro + newMoneyBox.TwoEuro;
        newMoneyBox.SumCent = newMoneyBox.OneCent + newMoneyBox.TwoCent + newMoneyBox.FiveCent + newMoneyBox.TenCent + newMoneyBox.TwentyCent + newMoneyBox.FifftyCent;

        Console.WriteLine("Sparschwein von:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Ein Cent Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.OneCent);
        Console.WriteLine("Zwei Cent Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.TwoCent);
        Console.WriteLine("Fünf Cent Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.FiveCent);
        Console.WriteLine("Zehn Cent Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.TenCent);
        Console.WriteLine("Zwanzig Cent Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.TwentyCent);
        Console.WriteLine("Fünfzig Cent Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.FifftyCent);
        Console.WriteLine("ein Euro Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.OneEuro);
        Console.WriteLine("Zwei Euro Münzen:");
        Console.WriteLine(newMoneyBox.TwoEuro);
        Console.WriteLine("************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Der Inhalt Ihres Sparschweins beträgt: " + newMoneyBox.SumEuro + "," + newMoneyBox.SumCent);
    }
    
    public static void ListOfMoneyBoxes()
    {
        foreach (var owner in moneyBoxes)
        {
            PrintMoneyBoxes(owner);
        }

        return;
        /*string nameOfMoneyBox = Console.ReadLine();

        //if ()
        {
            //Menü zum Ein-/ Auszahlen
        }*/
    } 

            
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string command = "";
        while(command != "exit")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("WILLKOMMEN ZU IHREM DIGITALEN SPARSCHWEIN");
            Console.WriteLine(">***************************************<");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Erstellen Sie ein neues Sparschwein und nehmen Sie Einzahlungen oder Auszahlungen vor:");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Erstellen eines neuen Sparschweins:      (e)");
            Console.WriteLine("Inhalt Ihres Sparschweins:               (i)");
            Console.WriteLine("Zahlen Sie Geld in Ihr Sparschwein ein:  (+)");
            command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            switch(command)
            {
                case "e":
                    AddmoneyBox();
                    break;
                case "i":
                    ListOfMoneyBoxes();
                    break;
                case "+":
                    DepositMoney();
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Well, you have a list of money boxes `moneyBoxes`. Maybe ask the user which money box they want to deposit in?

Comment: Could you show your `moneyBox` class?

Comment: OT that `newMoneyBox.SumEuro = newMoneyBox.OneEuro + newMoneyBox.TwoEuro;` counts the number of coins, not the money amount. Is that what you want?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes, i want to show only the number of coins. the amount comes under this later.

Comment: Just as a test, you can use `moneyBoxes[0]` as parameter for your `DepositMoney`. However, this ignores any other money box the user might have added and crashes when there is no box yet. But until you figure out how to select one particular box (see Sweeper's comment) you can at least test that method